# Why our "definitions" work so well?

Tags: logic, definition

The one thing common to all mathematical and physics concepts is that we 'assume' and 'define' various 'things'. I've not studied any branch of mathematics or physics in a very rigorous fashion, so I cannot give solid examples to substantiate my argument but I can surely list some of the examples which are elementary.

For example when we consider trigonometric functions of real numbers, what we do is define them. In this case we use unit circle definition, which according to me is arbitrary. We could define trigonometric functions by considering sine of a real number as twice of the ordinate of corresponding point on unit circle, cosine of a real number as one-half of the abscissa of the corresponding point on unit circle and tangent of a real number as square of ratio of sine of that number to the cosine of that number. This was an arbitrary definition and so is the definition which is used (unit circle definition).

So definition is purely arbitrary with no logic (according to me). But the problem I have is not with the definition we give but with the fact that it works so well in all possible applications which a person might not be aware while constructing the definition. So, for example, when we have to calculate work done on a particle at an angle, we blindly apply the formula wherein we substitute the value of cosine of the angle as per the definition, and receive the answer. The surprising thing is that what we receive by applying our "arbitrary definition" completely agrees with what actually happen. Like it is indeed easier to move a thing tied to a string making an acute angle with the direction of motion, than by applying force parallel to it.

Another example is the way vector addition is defined, which is also arbitrary. But in actual physical situations we find that our definition is correct. For example if we are rowing a boat in direction perpendicular to the motion of river, our resultant direction of motion is indeed somewhere between the two directions. So why our definition works which is purely arbitrary.

One possible explanation which came to my mind is that it must be looking at various applications, the definition is constructed. But, then again we can not possibly include every possible application of that concept, but mostly these definitions are quite general when it comes to applications.

So what is the reason behind this all. Any help is appreciated. I tried to explain myself best. Sorry for any discomfort.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, it is entirely arbitrary that we use certain sounds to mean certain concepts in any language, but what we choose to define is never arbitrary. We define things we want to talk about. We don't have a single word for pink elephants on a planet around Betelgeuse, because there is not use for such a word. But we might define such a word of such things were found, or if we were writing a science fiction novel.

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around (more often than not). We adapt definitions to our proofs. Hence it's no wonder that they work so beautifully.

Comment: what you understand by "arbitrary"?

Comment: These definitions "work so well" because although the definitions may seem arbitrary, the proofs that go after them and allow us to apply them (the "formulas" you mention are proven, they're not just blindly given and applied) are sound proofs: had you defined these things otherwise, they would probably not have the same properties and the formulas would be different, but they would still work. If you defined the cosine as half the distance that currently defines it, you would get the same formulas but with some $2$'s from time to time, that's all

Comment: @Masacroso By arbitrary I mean that the way we define is not universal and any other definition can equivalently be created. There is no restriction on how to define and we can define a thing differently.

Comment: Definition are arbitrary but only the "fittest" survive.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What do you mean by fittest ?

Comment: Motion and forces in nature compose according to the parallelogram rule...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That's what I'm asking. Why do the compose according to parallelogram rule which is defined and any other definition can be constructed.

Comment: @AbhinavDhawan I understand... The definitions used today comes from history, they are arbitrary in his form but they represent what they are intended to represent. The same happen with any definition of any word in any language.

Comment: If Mauro ALLEGRANZA is talking about physics, then I agree. But otherwise, in math, it is not as he said like "fittest" survives. Actually you can devise new thing in math and give it a definition. Will it be useful? The time will show it. But the reason you see that these definitions are so exact is that they are just so frequently used in different fields, subjects, etc. If you create something and give it a definition, then who knows, maybe after a lot of years someone will find it very useful and apply it. And maybe a whole theory will be constructed on it.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not satisfied. How our definitions work so well in varied applications. For example while defining trigonometric function, one is not expected to know all it's applications where it works perfectly presently. Is it possible that our presently accepted definitions will ever fail to explain certain applications or observations related to it.

Comment: @AbhinavDhawan, mathematical definition never fails. It is not physics. I don't know if you r aware, but I will say it. Mathmetics is not a science. Science use empirical techniques, where one definition can replace another one, as it closer defines some phenomena. But in math there are no experiments, and so on. People from science actually use mathemtical concepts to bring those phenomenas to numbers. And if you aware, not everything for now is precisely defined. That's why we also use numerical methods and so on. But the reason why nature works so, well, this is rather a philosophical topic

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov Can I not define vector addition in any other way I want. Also why can't our assumed mathematical assumptions ever fail when we can never prove them and all of maths is based on those assumptions.

Comment: @AbhinavDhawan, mathematical definitions are in compliance with what we want them to do. For example, consider the $(\epsilon,\delta)$ definition of limit: it captures our idea of infinitesimal quantities, consider the  definition of continuity, it captures our idea of a continuum. As for your example of trigonometry, you are right. The unit circle definition doesn't work for complex arguments; it is just an extension of the definition based on right triangles.

Comment: If I cannot define vector addition other way round, then what is the reason for accepting the present definition of it. Why is it so 'special'.

Comment: @AbhinavDhawan, math is not based on assumptions. All mathematical theorems are **logically** proved. Mathemtics was the first who separated from philosophy. So all theorems actually doesn't say anything about our nature. They are just logically true. They stay true even on Moon :) But it doesn't mean that you can apply these theorems there. The science deals with it, not math. Yes, I think, you can define vector addition in other way, but it will be better if you use another symbol for this operator. And maybe someone will find it useful to **apply** it in other field.

Comment: @Siddhant Does it mean that I can define something in any way I want. If it is so, it is possible that my definition cannot explain the present observations. What about that? And how do we know that our present definitions will work for all applications. Is it just assumed as you say that unit circle definition fails for complex arguments.

Comment: @AbhinavDhawan, sure you can do that, and it is possible that the definition may fail for some case. In that case, you either extend the definition, or you completely redefine it.

Comment: @AbhinavDhawan, and I think no ones suddenly gives a name, definition to something. Naming, taking conventions is a hard process I think. One of the way to accept some definition is to use that thing so frequently that you pay attention to it, find some kind of a pattern and decide to give it a name

Comment: So there is no reason to assume that present definitions are perfect and will work well in future also. It's only that they are successful until now and there is no guarantee that they will prove so in future also. The fact that why they are successful and why nature works that way is unanswered and in a way philosophical

Comment: Anyways thanks all of you for your support.

Comment: @AbhinavDhawan, math doesn't care about nature. If something fails then it is the care of science which deals with it. Math is about logic. There are no such terms like "clear", "perfect" definitions. They are just the way they are. That's all. It is up to you to create new theorems using these definitions. The most important is to logically prove them. That's all. Things end here. If someone finds relation between your theorem and nature, he will use it. But it is not related to math. His success, failures, nothing. Theorem is correct - that's all.

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov A thing with which I disagree with you is that how can you say that maths is not based on assumptions. It certainly is I suppose.

Comment: @AbhinavDhawan, well, can you please show an assumption? I mean really theorem, or concept which is hold as an assumption. Math is an abstraction. Here I agree with it. But it is not based on assumptions. If you mean the word "assume that" during proving something, then it is actually the way of proving. And mostly it is used in method by contradiction, which is considered as a weak proof.

Comment: I'm just an amateur, but have noticed the interplay between definition and proof. In many cases, I have noticed that getting the definitions right is sometimes the hardest part of proofs. You make a tentative definition of, say, addition on the natural numbers as a set of ordered triples and but you seem unable to even formally prove it is a function. You tweak your definition and go through the exercise again. When I did this some years ago, it took me 7 or 8 iterations to get the definition right. I also made sure that I could derive some basic algebraic properties: associativity, etc..

Comment: Well all of our axioms are assumptions according to me.

Comment: @AbhinavDhawan, oh, well, I got you. Actually you are free to define your axioms (any axioms) and prove theorems based on them. That's how all math sections are created: probability, game theory, etc. And this will mean nothing about nature. They are just logically correct, that's all.

Comment: Axioms, too, are subject to a kind of reality check. I had developed my own simplified set theory (for students) based very loosely on ZFC for an automated proof checker. One day, I somehow "discovered" that all sets are empty! This was not some profound insight but a bug in my program. Fortunately, it required only a minor tweak to my subset axiom. I had forgotten to make sure that the selection criteria did not refer to the new set. It was such a convenient "feature," too.

Comment: @DanChristensen, is your work private? If no, I would be glad if you share and let me look at it

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov  Visit my homepage at http://www.dcproof.com for a free, full-function download.

Comment: Your concept of "a definition working" is not mathematical. Hence my vote to close this as off-topic.

Comment: @RobArthan There are infinitely many binary functions definable on the natural numbers. How do we decide which one to call addition? It seems only one will work.

Comment: @DanChristensen: what do you mean by "work"? I can make a guess about that in the example you give:  "work" means  that addition on the natural numbers gives the free monoid on one variable (which leads to lots of nice properties). But the OP's general question "why do our definitions work so well" is too broad.

Comment: @RobArthan That is the sort of thing I meant. My point was that it is no coincidence that a formal definition works. I would think that coming up with workable definition is often a bit of a trial and error process. That may not be apparent to most people. Definitions are not something immutable sent down to us from the math gods on high. They may even evolve over time subject to the changing requirements of the day, e.g. from the tangent of Euclid's day to the tangent of Newton's day. If a definition doesn't work in a given application, it can be be replaced with one that does.

Comment: I wonder whether OP knows that for many centuries when people did trigonometry they didn't use the sine function but instead something called the *haversine* (look it up!). It took that long for folks to decide that what we now call the sine worked better. Similarly, Napier's definition of the (natural) logarithm was very different from the natural logarithm we now use. We don't always get it right the first time. Most of the world has given up on inches and gallons and Fahrenheit and ounces, not to mention furlongs and bushels.

Answer (score 5):

I am reminded of defensive play by Willy Mays referred to as [The Catch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Catch_(baseball)). Basically, he made an over-the-shoulder, running catch in deep center field, then immediately threw the ball to second base to stop the man on second base from scoring.

If you don't understand the game of baseball, you might think, "Big deal. He caught a ball and threw it to second base." Catching the ball over your shoulder while running at full speed, to where the is going to be, requires buckets-full of skill. He then had to get the ball out of his glove, into his hand, spin, and use the momentum of that spin to throw the ball to second base fast enough and accurately enough to make the runner not want to try for home plate.

You might wonder how Willie made that play look so easy. By the time he had to make that play, he knew exactly what to do and how to do it because he had worked out all of the problems in hundreds of practice sessions. Then, just to keep sharp, he had probably practiced it a few hundred times more.

The definitions of the trigonometric functions are like that. Believe me, there is nothing arbitrary about those definitions. You just don't see the years that mathematicians spent making it look as simple as they could.

If you want to really understand the definitions. You will have to find out about their history. Where did they come from? What problems did they solve? Simplicity of a definition is a result of a lot of hard work, failures and successes. There is nothing arbitrary about it.